# Fatal relocation error libocci.so.11.1 OCIServerAttach, __1c2N6FL_pv_ undefined symbols

Tags: oracle, compilation, driver, solaris, omnios

I have been trying to compile the oracle driver for naviserver (nsoracle). It compiles just fine but when I start up the server it complains during module load of nsoracle.so.

```
    Error: modload: /usr/local/ns/bin/nsoracle.so: couldn't load file "/usr/local/ns/bin/nsoracle.so": ld.so.1: nsd: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/local/ns/bin/nsoracle.so: symbol OCIServerDetach: referenced symbol not found
```

The library/linking line in the Makefile looks like this:

```
    MODLIBS  += -R$(ORACLE_HOME}:${ORACLE_HOME}/lib:$NSHOME/bin:$NSHOME/lib -L$(ORACLE_HOME):$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib:$(NSHOME)/lib -L$(ORACLE_HOME):$(ORACLE_HOME)/lib:$(NSHOME)/lib  -locci -lclntsh -lnnz11
```

ORACLE_HOME contains libocci.so.11.1 libclntsh.11.1 libociei.so libnnz11.so lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out oracle compiles it's instant client libraries using SunStudio using libraries not present in illumos(I run OmniOS) or GNU gcc distributions.

libCrun.so and libCstd.so are required to properly link instantclient (specifically libocci.so.11.1) against nsoracle or other projects.

You can use a source like the pkg install command  for omnios

```
   pkg install sunstudio12.1
```

Also check [here](https://superuser.com/questions/424992/how-do-i-find-the-version-of-sun-studio-11-installed-on-my-solaris-10-server) for other options for obtaining Sun Studio

The gmake command I finally used that worked for me:

```
   gmake MODLIBS+="-L/opt/sunstudio12.1/lib/amd64 -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -L/usr/local/ns/lib -R/opt/sunstudio12.1/lib/amd64 -R$ORACLE_HOME/lib  -R/usr/local/ns/lib -lCrun -lCstd -locci -lclntsh -lociei -lnnz11 -lnsthread -lnsdb -lnsd -ltcl8.5"
```

You would change  /opt/sunstudio12.1/lib/amd64 to /opt/sunstudio12.1/lib if performing a 32 bit compile.

Comment: Do not expect to be able to link that library into programs compiled with GCC and have it work.  See https://community.oracle.com/thread/1994953?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: It has been working just fine so far, my server has been able to correctly connect to an oracle database where it was previously unable to do so. Is there any cause for concern. My first attempt I actually did attempt to use sun's cc but the makefile ignored it and linked correctly, if there is good reason I would definitely be willing to go back and recompile with Sun CC.